# Накопление данных в excel

Tags: delphi

Вот кусок кода который создает файл Экселя.

```
function TForm7.GetExcelSaveAs: String;
begin
    Result:= SaveDialog1.FileName + '.xls';
end;

procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ExcelApp, Sheet: variant;
  Col, Row: Word;
begin
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    begin
        ExcelApp:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
        try
            ExcelApp.Visible:= False;
            ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add;
            Sheet:= ExcelApp.ActiveWorkBook.WorkSheets[1];
            for Col:= 0 to StringGrid1.ColCount -1 do
                for Row:= 0 to StringGrid1.RowCount -1 do
                     Sheet.Cells[Row + 1, Col +1]:= StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row];
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(GetExcelSaveAs);
        finally
            ExcelApp.Application.Quit;
            ExcelApp:= Unassigned;
            Sheet:= Unassigned;
        end;
    end;
    ShowMessage('Сохранение завершено!');
end;
```

Как сделать так чтобы при следующем расчете программы(в предыдущих модулях) новые расчеты попадали уже в созданный файл(добавление в файл новых результатов расчета) а старые не исчезал(не перезаписывались)?

Comment: Кстати, в форме редактирования вопроса есть кнопочка для форматирования кода

Answer (score 1):

Ну очевидно через

```
ExcelApp:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application'); 
try 
    ExcelApp.Visible:= False;    
    ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add; 
    Sheet:= ExcelApp.Open(GetExcelSaveAs); 
    ...
```

Comment: Вы можете наглядно показать куда что надо вставлять?я не сильно силен в Делфи!

Comment: На этом сайте приветствуются конкретные технические вопросы с неочевидным решением. А если Вы нашли где-то кучку кода, написанного, судя по названию переменных, лишь бы побыстрее отвязаться, а теперь просите "сделайте тут за меня, мне неохота разбираться", то это неинтересно